# How many epochs should I iterate for tuning an ANN?

Tags: neural-networks, hyperparameter, tuning

I have been using Keras-Tuner for tuning my ANN before going into training. The tuner seems to be iterating forever even though I set a limit of 1000 epochs.

After that, I have decided to terminate the tuning process after 500 epochs. However, I am not sure what to do actually.

How many epochs should I iterate for tuning an ANN so that I can obtain the best result for my ANN?

Comment: “ tuning my ANN before going into training”—what?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, I am tuning the ANN to find how many neurons should I use in the hidden layers to get the maximum validation accuracy. Am I incorrect?